# W/SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I have an angular app which I try to wrap in a cordova application for android. But I fail at whitelisting the requests against a server, when the cordova app on android.
When testing the cordova application as a browser application, there are no problems.
I've already read many articles and posts regarding the whitelisting behaviour on cordova, but without any results.

I'm using cordova 10. As I read, I should not use the cordova-plugin-whitelist, because in this version this plugin is already integrated in the main framework. The configuration in config.xml was already generated automatic when creating the project.
Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="de.acme.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>appname</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <author email="user@mail.de" href="https://mail.de">author</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

As you see, the tag with the access origin is available.
I have no plugins installed. But I also tried to install the cordova-plugin-whitelist. But this also makes no difference.

The requests in Angular are standard GET requests with the HTTPClient. But also other requests does not work. For example the embedding of google fonts.

The server, I want to access with my GET requests is a server in my LAN with the following address: 192.168.178.5:4003 (specific port!)

In Logcat I receive this error message:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "request: http://192.168.178.5:4003/api/audiobooks/tags", source: file:///android_asset/www/main.a7f87f00e27ff7637d70.js (1)
W/SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist: http://192.168.178.5:4003/api/audiobooks/tags
```

I think, this is just a small configuration problem. But I have no idea, where I should look for a correct solution.

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTP, you might need to allow Android to use clear text traffic. See: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/index.html#android-quirks

If you are on cordova-android 10 make sure to use the latest version (10.1.0), as it contains important bug fixes.